# Black colomns in OpenNI

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, kinect, openni

I'm working on one of the OpenNI samples and when analyzing the depth data I found that the first 7 columns are always zeros! so I'm trying to figure out why this is happening?
I've attached a photo describing the issue, and I marked the the are in red box[image: black columns].

Many Thanks